# Most convenient way to save data and make backups in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-backups

one of my colleagues suggested that I should make different databases (MySQL) for each client, so that if one account is compromised, we only need to restore a backup of a single database. I'm concerned about a fast access to the data: which is faster? selecting a database among thousands of them, or finding an entry among thousands on a table from a single database? And also, what's more convenient, in terms of speed and reliability: to backup a large database, or a large number of little ones? Also, Is there a way to backup only one entry in a table, and if there is, is it better than backing up lots of little databases or a large one?

The system I'm using is based on PHP/MySQL and jQuery (Javascript and AJAX), if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to use a **different database per client**.  Using a different database is much faster than trying to query a record from a combined table schema as well as being more secure(if you use different accounts per database).

Depending on your database engine, **MYISAM** or **INNODB**, etc there are different backup strategies as well.  Other performance issues for instance, MYISAM is table level locking when a record is being updated which will be very slow if everything is using the same table.

Depending on your **backup strategy** and database engine you can use [**mysqldump**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) or [**mysqlhotcopy**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlhotcopy.html) for on the fly backups if you use MYISAM tables.